displaying php variable name from sql result
I'm trying to pass a php variable name to mysql and then retrieve the variable name back where it displays the appropriate value.
UPDATE: APOLOGIES:
As each page will have a different VARIABLEVALUE as called by MySql.
::UPDATE ENDED::
Currently I'm using mysqli, with varchar, but should I be using text? or is this irrelevant.
Data stored in contentData on mysql is as such:
$variableName = VARIABLEVALUE;

So SQL dataRow is:

Some data and information $variableName some data and information

php code i am trying to use to retieve the text and variable is:
$variable = $row_mysqlresult['contentData'];

I'm calling the data as above, but also re-indexing to:
$variable = '. $variable .';
echo = $variable ;

This now displays

Some data and information $variableName some data and information

Instead of

Some data and information VARIABLEVALUE some data and information

I think I've just overcomplicated what I'm trying to do...
Any help, much appreciated :))

If I understand correctly, you just have a concatenation or interpolation problem? https://3v4l.org/Jjg5Z

Sorry, I do not understand. Please give an example of what you want to put in and what you want get back. Btw. echo = $variable ; is no valid syntax.

The difference between TEXT and VARCHAR is irrelevant to PHP. It mainly affects the storage efficiency in the DB.

When you pass a variable to a function, the function receives the variable's value, it can't get the variable name. If names are significant, you probably should be using an associative array, not separate variables.

$variable = '. $variable .'; just makes a string whose contents are " $variable " (i.e  a space, a $, the word "variable" and another space). Variable names in single-quoted strings in PHP aren't transformed into the variable value. If you want to add spaces either side of the string you need double-quotes here. I'm also guessing the .s aren't really what you wanted? So try: $variable = " $variable ";
